# Jenkins - Prefix all logs with node name?

Tags: jenkins, logging, prefix

What I am looking for is basically the same functionality that [Timestamper](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/) provides, but in addition to showing the time for each line, I also want to see which node it was running on.

Instead of this:

```
13:35:12  > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
13:35:12  > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
13:35:12  > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
13:35:12  > Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
13:35:12  > Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
13:35:12  > Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
13:36:39    fatalError
```

I want this (or similar):

```
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
13:35:12 [mac-01] > Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
13:36:39 [mac-01]   fatalError
```

We have pipelines that run multiple builds on multipe nodes in parallel and sometimes they fail due to problems with a specific node. If each line in the log was prefixed with the node it was running on, it would be quite trivial to find out which node is having an issue. As it stands now, it can be rather challenging.

I've been trying to search for something like this on Google, but the terms are a bit too generic and I'm not getting any relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is label attribute.

This label attribute is available for all bat, sh, powershell and others.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script

````
bat( script: ```Some Script ```,
     label: "${env.NODE_NAME}"
 )
````

Your execution will then be pre fixed with the NODE_NAME where the task is running.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but updating all of our `sh` steps to have a label seems far from ideal. Do you by any chance know if there is a global setting to set a default label?

Comment: Build Time Stamp Plugin supports literal maybe you can try putting this pattern in ```yyyy.MM.dd G 'running at ${env.NODE_NAME}'```. Unfortunately i cannot try that out on our instance... You can check it and let me know.

Comment: That was actually one of the first things I tried. It doesn't work unfortunately.